# Spring Boot Mongo Repository autogenerated ID not updating

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

I'd like to get autogenerated id from the inserted entity after inserting a new entity to MongoDB using MongoRepository. I've annotated `@Id` to `_id` field and set it as an empty string.

I've tried to save the entity with `repository.save(entity)` and checked that entity has been saved with autogenerated id. But when I access to id field, autogenerated id isn't updated.

Is there any way to get autogenerated  id from `repository.save(entity)`?

```
@Document(collection = "data")
data class Data(
    @Id
    val _id: String = "",
    val data: String
)

repository.save(Data(data = "data")).awaitSingle()._id // Results in empty string.
```

Comment: does something alone the line of `val _id: String = ObjectId().toHexString()` solves your issue? Of course you can use the actual ObjectId object if you want instead of the string representation.

Comment: remove the ": String = ""

Comment: @BookOfZeus Then what should I set value for id? Generate id by myself? I'd like to get id from autogenerated id from MongoDB.

Comment: try changing `val` to `var`

Comment: @ksik "repository.save" will return your object with the system generated value, otherwise use: new ObjectId(); .. but I dont recommend it